# Verwendung von "um sich"

Tags: reflexive

Ich lerne Deutsch auf Duolingo. In einer Übung habe ich folgenden Satz gesehen:

> "Marie geht in ihr Lieblingscafé, um sich wie jeden Morgen ihren Lieblingsmuffin zu kaufen."

Kann man diesen Satz genau so konstruieren:

> "Marie geht in ihr Lieblingscafé, wie jeden Morgen ihren Lieblingsmuffin zu kaufen."

Ich verstehe nicht wieso man "um sich" zu nutzen hat.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Die Phrase lautet nicht "um sich" (around herself), sondern "um ... zu kaufen" (in order to buy). "Sich etw. kaufen" bedeutet nur, daß die Käuferin auch die Verwenderin ist. Der Satz ist also auch ohne "sich" möglich, aber nicht ohne "um ... zu":

> "Marie geht in ihr Lieblingscafé, um wie jeden Morgen ihren Lieblingsmuffin zu kaufen."

Comment: Wobei das dann sehr seltsam klingt, ich kaufe ja nicht meinen Lieblingsmuffin für jemand anderen. Also, entweder kaufe ich ihn für mich selbst, oder ich lasse es ganz sein. Aber grammatikalisch korrekt kann man es natürlich so ausdrücken. (Ist vielleicht aber auch einfach eine Stil-Frage, ich würde das "sich" jedenfalls nicht weg lassen wollen.)

Comment: @BodoThiesen Sie kann aber ins Café gehen, um ihrem Sohn seinen Lieblingsmuffin zu kaufen

Answer (score 3):

Es gibt im Deutschen einige Infinitivsätze, die ausnahmsweise keinen Objektsatz ersetzen:

> Er ignorierte die rote Ampel, **um** den Bus noch **zu** erreichen.

Diese Sorte Infinitivsatz gibt einen Grund an.

> Er ignorierte die rote Ampel, **(an)statt** auf Grün **zu** warten.

Diese Sorte Infinitivsatz gibt die erwartete Alternative an.

> Er ignorierte die rote Ampel, **ohne** auf den Verkehr **zu** achten.

Diese Sorte Infinitivsatz gibt die nicht vorgenommenen Handlungen an.

---

Dein Beispiel enthält genau so einen Infinitivsatz, der mit **um** eingeleitet wird. Der Satz gibt also den Grund an, warum Marie in ihr Lieblingscafé geht.

> Marie geht in ihr Lieblingscafé, **um** sich wie jeden Morgen ihren Lieblingsmuffin **zu** kaufen."

Dein zweites Beispiel lässt das *um* aus. Solche "normalen" Infinitivsätze ersetzen jedoch ein Objekt im Hauptsatz (meist das Akkusativobjekt), und in deinem Hauptsatz fehlt keins. Daher ist der Satz falsch.

> <s>Marie geht in ihr Lieblingscafé, wie jeden Morgen ihren Lieblingsmuffin zu kaufen.</s>

---

Richtig wäre aber zum Beispiel:

> Heute hat Marie vergessen, wie jeden Morgen ihren Lieblingsmuffin zu kaufen. *(bevorzugt)*
>
> Heute hat Marie vergessen, dass sie wie jeden Morgen ihren Lieblingsmuffin kauft.

Das Verb *vergessen* verlangt ein Akkusativobjekt – die Sache, die vergessen wird. Dieses Objekt wird entweder durch den Infinitivsatz ersetzt, oder durch den mit *dass* eingeleiteten Objektsatz. Den Objektsatz verwendet man normalerweise nur, wenn das Subjekt von dem Subjekt des Hauptsatzes abweicht. Das ist hier nicht der Fall (beide Male ist Marie das Subjekt), daher wird der Infinitivsatz bevorzugt.

Answer (score 2):

Die Wörter "um" und "sich" sind hier keine Redewendung, sondern unabhängig voneinander.

Das "um" in "Sie geht, um zu kaufen" kann auch geschrieben werden als "Sie geht, weil sie kaufen will". Es gibt den Zweck an, warum die Aktion aus dem Hauptsatz ausgeführt wird.

Das "sich" bezieht sich nicht auf "um", sondern auf "kaufen". Sie kauft etwas für sich selbst, nicht für jemand anderen. Da man in den meisten Fällen etwas für sich selbst und nicht für andere kauft, kann man das Wort "sich" an der Stelle auch weglassen und der Sinn bleibt der gleiche.

In dem zweiten Satz kann man also das "sich" weglassen, aber nicht das "um", weil der Nebensatz erklärt, warum sie in ihr Lieblingscafé geht.

> "Marie geht in ihr Lieblingscafé, um wie jeden Morgen ihren Lieblingsmuffin zu kaufen."

Es gibt andere Fälle, wo "um sich" zusammen gehört, wie "Er schlägt um sich", aber hier ist das nicht der Fall.